# React.js - use DOM elements from different levels of component hierarchy

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

We need to perform some actions related to DOM elements in different parts of the component hierarchy, on `window.onresize` and `window.onscroll`:

1) Moving elements when resizing to mobile resolution

2) Changing classes and styles when scrolling.

The problem is that the elements are in different levels of the React component hierarchy, i.e. nested in different components. Thus if I understand correctly, I can't use `refs` to access the DOM nodes.

I have:
`{someCondition ? <FirstComponent/>: <SecondComponent/>}`

Whereas `someCondition` can change either due to user UI actions, or it could be true from the beginning of the page load.

I've tried using `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` on my `FirstComponent`, but found that `componentDidMount` only fires if `someCondition` is true from the beginning, and `componentDidUpdate` indeed fires when `someCondition` changes, but then the required DOM elements (contained in the component) are not ready at that point, and `document.getElementById` fails.

Adding `window.requestAnimationFrame` did not help.

I imagine there should be a solid way to do this in React?

Maybe `React.findDomNode`?

Thank you.

Comment: Generally shouldn't be using `document.getElementById` (`React.findDOMNode` is usually the way to do this, but you mentioned something about not being able to use `ref`s? Can you expand on that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is the antithesis of React.  It is an approach I would expect when using an imperative jQuery/Dojo based framework.

With React, you are developing functional components that know how to convert state into rendered HTML and you need to approach the problem differently.

For your problem, your `window.onresize` and `window.onscroll` callbacks should *not* try to manipulate the React DOM elements.  Instead it should just update state and let React re-render.  Your React components should receive this state and render accordingly.

Here's a simple example where the main app listens to these events and updates its state, which triggers a re-render.  The app passes the state as props to the children.  The children use the props to conditionally change their css class names.  They could easily render different html or inline styles as well.

```
const Component2 = ({someCondition2}) => {
    const className = someCondition2 ? "foo" : "bar";
    return <div className={className}>Hello</div>;
};

const Component1 = ({someCondition1, someCondition2}) => {
    const className = someCondition1 ? "A" : "B";
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <Component2 someCondition2={someCondition2} />
        </div>
    );
};

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        someCondition: false,
        someCondition2: true,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.onresize = ev => {
            const someCondition = ev.xxx;
            // re-render with the new state
            this.setState({ someCondition });
        };

        window.onscroll = ev => {
            const someCondition2 = ev.xxx;
            this.setState({ someCondition2 });
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {someCondition, someCondition2} = this.state;
        return (
           <Component1
              someCondition1={someCondition1}
              someCondition2={someCondition2} />
        );
    }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Hmmm. That sounds correct and solves the fundamental problem I was having. We are using Redux to manage global state and I need to manipulate multiple components during scroll. As this would require updating the global state and reacting to changes in it on every scroll event - should I be concerned about performance?

Comment: The answer to "Should I be concerned about performance" is almost always "not unless you've encountered a performance issue and traced it back to this".  Just try it and see.  If you *do* encounter a performance issue, a good first step is to throttle or debounce your onscroll handler so that it doesn't get called quite as much.